# Wordpress Admin and JavaScript

Tags: php, wordpress

Im writing a plugin and have allot of custom Javascript. (shudder). I would like to only enque these javascript and other assets when needed. They are loaded on my plugin pages and also will be neede on the post / page / custom post type edit screens. Is there a simple and best practice method for doing so?

cheers

Comment: What's wrong with Javascript? :)

Comment: I'd like someone to point out whats right with it first... I'm going to move onto googles Java -> javascript interpreter ASAP! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [`load-(page)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-%28page%29) action function to conditionally add your enqueue calls on specific pages.

```
add_action('load-post.php', 'my_load_post_php_action');
function my_load_post_php_action() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my_script', plugins_url('my_script.js', __FILE__));
}
```

Comment: hmm ok this seems to be along the right track. Although that would mean i would have many action / call backs to init the same scripts / styles... or maybe i could use the same callback in multiple actions.. :-) good idea what do you think

   `add_action('load-post.php', 'enque_scripts');
   add_action('post.php', 'enque_scripts');
   add_action('edit-post.php', 'enque_scripts');

   function enque_scripts() {
      wp_enqueue_script('my_script', plugins_url('my_script.js', __FILE__));

   }`

Answer (score 0):

Use enqueue script, that will avoid all JS conflicts.

A better explanation on this link:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: im aware of enque functions in wp, and i am using them. Although i would like to only load the JS when it is needed on certin pages, as stated above. As i would like to lessen the chance of conflicts and also reduce the code. ...